# Double quotes in regular expression control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

In my below mentioned reqular expression, how can i add double quotes ?

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator SetFocusOnError="true" ID="rev" runat="server"
                                Display="None" ValidationGroup="question" ErrorMessage="" ControlToValidate="txtQuestion"
                                ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z-/'? ]+$"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Can you clarify... Do you want to be able to let the user add any number of double quotes?

Comment: If you want both quotes you just have to escape one. Otherwise your .xml will not be valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like it may be an XML question more than regex. Have you tried just using `&quot;`?

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z-/'?&quot; ]+$">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
 \&quot;
```

Cause, it's encoded in HTML.

You have to keep in mind than ASP page are render in XHTML (like XML) and then you should encode regexp in order to have seems correct in XML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking but if you are asking how to add quotes to your regular expression I would point you to this [cheat sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet).