# RegEx No Special characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am having allot of trouble finding a regex that will allow me to throw a error if the user tries to submit special characters especially `"/"` `"\"`. I have a expression already that helps with other special characters but not the forward and backward slash  Bonus: I don't want these ether but its not likely they will be entered. `~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,()`.

I am currently using `^[\w{./\\(),'}+:?®©-]+$`

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: I am going to use it in a asp.net RegularExpression validator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex you have specifically *allows* `/` and `\` (as well as `(` and `)`). Change it like so:

```
^[\w{.,'}+:?®©-]+$
```

and keep removing any other characters you don't want to allow either.

In case you're wondering, the construct `[...]` is called a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

You can also use a *negated* character class like `^[^/\\()~!@#$%^&*]*$` to allow any characters *except* `/\()~!@#$%^&*`.

Comment: Thank you! You also gave me a better understanding of how they are written.

Comment: *negated* character class helped me. However just a little query. How do I escape double inverted comma (i.e. `"`)? Actually I want to disallow these characters: `~\`!#$%^=+|\:'",;[]{}()` and I am trying this: `ValidationExpression="^[^\\~\`\[\]\(\)\{}!#\$%\^=\+\|:',;\"]*$"` But it says the double inverted comma is not escaped properly. Any solution?

Comment: @hims056: I think you have to escape double quotes by doubling. Could you try `ValidationExpression="^[^\\~\`\[\](){}!#\$%^=+|:',;""]*$"`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I just tried. But it gives an error as well.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I just found [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7819001/1369235). No doubt why he is legend.